# passing fetched data as a parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parameters, fetch-api

I'm struggling with this issue for a couple of days now, hope you could help me out.

In this app, I'm getting data from an `API` to *App.js, passing it as a parameter to the *Boxx.js component which renders the data inside.
The main problem is, that Boxx.js doesn't get the data at the right time so the values/functions that you passed it will never run.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Boxx from './Boxx';
function App(){
var [data,setData] = React.useState(null)
var [status, setStatus] = React.useState(false)
React.useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions?categories=science,society_and_culture&limit=5')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(result=>setData(result)).finally(()=>{setStatus(true)})
},[])

return(
<div className='App--'>
{status && <Boxx question={data[0].question} answers={data[0].answers}}
</div>
)

}
```

Boxx.js

```
import React from "react";
import './index.css'

export default function Boxx (prop) {
    
return(
   <div className="questionBody--">
       <p className='qB--question'>{prop.question}</p>
       <div className="answers--">
           <p className="qB--answer" id='0'>{prop.answers[1]}</p>
           <p className="qB--answer" id='1'>{prop.answers[0]}</p>
           <p className="qB--answer" id='2'>{prop.answers[2]}</p>
       </div>

   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Boxx.js doesn't get the data at the right time"? What error did you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I got something like: /data is not defined/ 
I've solved this issue as I but the data that comes from App.js  in an async function so the Boxx component could render it after it arrives from the server

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what's the error you are stuck at. So i am just taking a stab here.

You want to render `Boxx` component only when data is ready. For that you can just do this

```
<div className='App--'>
{data && data.length > 0 && <Boxx question={data[0].question} answers={data[0].answers}}
</div>
```

There is no need to set an additional flag `status`

Comment: Sorry, my English isn't that good so I posted the code hoping that someone could understand it :-)
Yeah, I've done something like this above but it's not a clean solution since I had to map over the data, and for each piece of it, I had to create a <Boxx/>
I've solved the problem, it was kinda silly, I just had to put the data that comes from App.js inside of an async function, and then I could put it inside of a state. 
Anyway, fetching took some time so I've created another page like "click me to run" that the user has to spend a bit of time on it until the fetching progress is finished